# Differentiation Question, Please help!

Tags: derivatives, word-problem

The curve $y = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + 5$ passes through the point $P(-1, 4)$ and at the point P the first and second derivatives of the curve are $8$ and $-24$ respectively. Find the values of the constants $a$ , $b$ and $c$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Have you found the 3 equations for $a,b,c$ that follow from (1) the value at -1, (2) the value of the derivative at -1, (3) the value of the 2nd derivative at -1? If so, what is the difficulty about solving them for $a,b,c$?

Comment: Just like the answer below (by Jan), I completed the derivatives (both first and second) and then I substituted the values of point P (x=-1 and y=4). And then I didn't know what to do so I used simultaneous equation to solve them. That's where I went wrong. Also, what I didn't do was substitute the values of P to the original equation. Thank you Arthur, almagest and Jan.